# Unable to import Python packages into Vim

Tags: python, plugin-ale

I have to get into some python programs so I thought I'd edit my Vim workflow so that Python is optimally efficient too.

I have quite some packages (vim airline, vim ale, ...), a virtual environment for python where the necessary packages are downloaded and Vim has python3 feature enabled (python feature not though but I think that is fine?).

However, when I import packages such as `yfinance` in my `pythonscript.py` at the top using `import yfinance as yf`, I get an error saying that "
`Unable to import 'yfinance'`.

If I run the python script from the terminal using `python3 pythonscript.py`, everything is fine since the packages are installed there, but they don't seem to transfer to Vim.

Is there some setting that I have to enable for my packages to be carried over to Vim too?

Comment: How do you run your script into Vim? Which Vim command do you use?

Comment: It is not Vim that is telling you `Unable to import 'yfinance'`, but one of the plugins you didn't care to list exhaustively, and it probably does it on behalf of some underlying and unspecified program anyway. You should put more effort into solving your problems before involving others.

Comment: What is the value of the `g:python3_host_prog` variable (`:echo g:python3_host_prog`)?

Comment: Hi @Vivian, `:echo g:python3_host_prof` gives back an undefined variable error. And @Friedrich, I didn't know that! Everywhere I read that the python3 feature has to be enabled so I thought it was important...

Comment: @Airbornedawn345 I made that comment part of my answer. The `python3` feature is certainly important if you have plugins that are implemented in Python. There's no `english` feature but you can still write English text in Vim :-)

Comment: Good point, thanks @Friedrich. You solved my issue!

Comment: @Airbornedawn345 it the solution address your problem maybe could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: Oh, I think I already did that? Big green check mark is next to the question?

Comment: My answer was accepted, thank you very much. Thanks for asking on my behalf
@VivianDeSmedt, it is much appreciated.

Comment: With the css I didn't saw that :-| I have to get used to it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "error" you see is probably *virtual text* written by ALE and caused by one of the static code checkers run by it. Turning ALE off with `:ALEDisable` should make the errors disappear.

One of the linters is unaware of the virtual environment you're in and does not find its packages.

Reading through `:ALEInfo` will show which linters are run and their errors.

I've seen these caused by `pylint` but I can't tell if it's the same for you.

A quick and dirty solution is to add your virtual environment's `site-packages` directory to `PYTHONPATH` e.g. like this:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(echo $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python*/site-packages):$PYTHONPATH
vim mypythonfile.py
```

There's a question on SO [pylint doesn't point to virutalenv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923090/pylint-doesnt-point-to-virtualenv-python) which seems related.
One of the answers there suggest to install `pylint` *in* the virtual environment to solve the issue.

---

In your question, you mention the `python` and `python3` features that show in `:version`. These say whether Vim itself is able to interpret Python 2.7 or Python 3.x code, respectively. You can *write* code in any language (natural or programming) without those features.

Comment: I was able to solve it by pip installing pylint in my virtual environment. I didn't expect ALE to be the problem. Thank you very much!